# elasticsearch: how can i boost documents having sub-objects

Tags: elasticsearch

How can i *boost* documents having sub-objects over documents without having such sub-objects even if i don't query directly for information of sub-objects?

Here an example:

I put events in my search index. Each event has a name and optional one ore more dates. you can search for events by name. I want the matching events with dates to become the first results. Events that also match by name but don't have a date should come afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create "has_dates" field and use boosting query boosting objects with "has_dates" field.